# Is this adaptive MCMC approach ergodic?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, ergodic

I am aware that adaptive MCMC proposals can be dangerous, as they can affect the ergodicity of the chain and hence potentially invalidate the results obtained. Andrieu & Thoms (2008) (DOI 10.1007/s11222-008-9110-y) suggest that adaptive mechanisms with vanishing adaptation might be a valid way to restore ergodicity.

I was wondering if the following adaptive MCMC proposal would suit these requirements for a multivariate Gaussian proposal:

> Initialize counter c = 0
>
> At every $n$-th proposal:
>
> c = c+1
>
> Estimate a base covariance $\Sigma_{base}$ based on the unique samples
> in the chain
>
> Calculate the acceptance rate $r_{acc}$ in since the last $n$-th step
>
> Adjust a scalar factor $f_{c} = f_{c-1}((\frac{r_{acc}}{r_{target}}-1)1.1^{-c}+1)$
>
> Set proposal covariance to $\Sigma_{proposal}=f_{c}\Sigma_{base}$$

As far as I see, $\Sigma_{base}$ should approach stability as the length of the chain approaches infinity, and the changes in the adaptation factor $f$ obviously approach zero as the chain grows. This seems like a vanishing procedure, but is there something I have missed?